# Am puzzled on how I would be able to pass what is given inside the textfield for size into my size int

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

```
package SOS;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SOS");
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        
        JLabel sizelabel = new JLabel("Board size:");
        frame.add(sizelabel);
        sizelabel.setBounds(500, 100, 30, 30);

        JTextField boardsize = new JTextField();
        boardsize.setBounds(500, 100, 30, 30);
        frame.add(boardsize);
        String value = boardsize.getText();

        BoardPanel panel = new BoardPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    static final int size = Integer.parseInt(boardsize.getText());;
    
    static final int cols = size;
    static final int rows = size;
    
    static final int originX = 73/size;
    static final int originY = 97/size;
    static final int cellSize = 300/size;
    }
}
```

Just having trouble figuring out how I would be able to pass `String value = boardsize.getText();` to static `final int size = Integer.parseInt(boardsize.getText());;` I tried figuring out ways how to make it not inside the main but I got lost.

I am new to java as well so this whole scoping issue/global variable problem is new to me here.

Comment: See [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Note that used the way this frame is being used, only one of `sizelabel`, `boardsize` or `panel` will appear, and fortunately not at the bounds set (they overlap) for the first two (which will be ignored by the layout manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question does not compile because `boardsize` is a local variable in method `main` and so cannot be accessed from outside of that method. Hence the following line does not compile:

```java
static final int size = Integer.parseInt(boardsize.getText());
```

Refer to [this Web page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), entitled *Variables*, from Oracle's Java tutorials.

The first *Swing* code examples on the Internet all used classes that extended either `JPanel` or `JFrame`. This is no longer required. Hence `BoardPane` does not need to extend `JPanel`.

There is a series of steps that you need to follow when writing any GUI application – not just a *Swing* application.

First you create the application window. Then you add components to the window. Then you write code that is executed when the user performs a certain action, for example when she enters text into a [JTextComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) or when she clicks on a [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). The code that gets executed in response to a user action is referred to as an [event listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html).

Here is a rewrite of your application. The user enters a number into the `JTextField` and presses the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. This will invoke method `createBoard`. Note that I use a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). I assume that you want to create some sort of board so I created a grid of `JLabel`s.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BordPane {
    private JFrame frame;

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTopPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createBoard(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) source;
            String text = textField.getText();
            int dimension = Integer.parseInt(text);
            JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(dimension, dimension));
            for (int row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
                    JLabel square = new JLabel("   ");
                    square.setBackground(Color.white);
                    square.setOpaque(true);
                    square.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    board.add(square);
                }
            }
            frame.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
        }
    }

    private JPanel createTopPanel() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Board size:");
        topPanel.add(label);
        JTextField boardSize = new JTextField(6);
        boardSize.addActionListener(this::createBoard);
        topPanel.add(boardSize);
        return topPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new BordPane().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

I recommend that you go through the entire [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) trail in Oracle's Java tutorials.